# html & php form to database entering 0000-00-00 for date instead of the html5 datepicker date chosen

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an html form and a connect php file in order to insert information from a webpage to a database. My html5 is under date which automatically produces a datepicker. The php has been adjusted to properly format the date, however, when it inserts into the database, it inserts 0000-00-00 instead of the date chosen on the html datepicker.

I have used many different snippets of code from this site and from Google in an attempt to get it to work. I have failed to get any of them to function. The following code is the closest that I have come. I really prefer the html5 datepicker as the people using this form need to always be choosing Monday dates. Please note that the date field is part of a multi-field form and all fields work except described.

HTML FORM

```
<form method="POST" action="connect.php">

Week Beginning : <input type="date" name="WeekBeginning"><br>
Submit : <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

php

```
$wkBeg = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'WeekBeginning');

else{
$wkBeg = strtotime($_POST["WeekBeginning"]);
$wkBeg = date('y-m-d H:i:s', $date);


$sql = "INSERT INTO `op_pont_totalactualhours`(WeekBeginning) VALUES ('$date')";
```

I expect if choosing 2019 Jan 07 from the datepicker calendar, that it would be entered into the database as 2019-01-07 but instead it shows up as 0000-00-00. I could use some guidance as I am unable to take the examples from other similar questions and make them work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is not using the correct new set variables.

```
$wkBeg = strtotime($_POST["WeekBeginning"]);
$wkBeg = date('y-m-d H:i:s', $date);


$sql = "INSERT INTO `op_pont_totalactualhours`(WeekBeginning) VALUES ('$date')";
```

- Line 1: You set $wkBeg
- Line 2: Now you are using $date in the date() function, which is not set.
- Line 3: You try to insert the not set $date

---

I would suggest:

```
$wkBeg = strtotime($_POST["WeekBeginning"]);
$wkBeg = date('y-m-d H:i:s', $wkBeg);


$sql = "INSERT INTO `op_pont_totalactualhours`(WeekBeginning) VALUES ('$wkBeg')";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had looked at it so long that I just could not see it. Very appreciated!